# defining enum types in a mapping file, or columns from another table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

if my mapping file, how would I reference a C# enum type?
what about columns from another table?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use Int32 type in your mapping file. Or if you want to use the string representation of your enum then you use [EnumStringType](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2006/02/20/138732.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than Int32 you can use your actual enum type directly in the NHibernate mapping file. For example if you are mapping an object with a MyEnum property of type Example.NameSpace.MyEnum:

```
<property name="MyEnum" type="Example.NameSpace.MyEnum">
</property>
```